# Wine can't run bad exe file

Tags: wine, directory, executable

I'm trying to download an application and wine keeps giving me the message of a bad exe file.

I've tried the simple `cd /Downloads` and then `wine applicationname.exe` but I got the error message and tried to look up what I was doing wrong. I tried to change wine to the 64 bit over the 32 bit, but I can't tell whether I have done so or not.

I then tried to create a wine64 directory and run it through there with `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine /home/user/Downloads/applicationname.exe` but it renders the same bad exe file message.

I'm not great with terminal commands and would appreciate some assistance. Thanks!

Comment: That means that the file is really bad ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Is that similar to your situation?

> it appears you are trying to run a 32 bit app with pure 64 bit Wine.
>   That won't work. Try the WineHQ Debian package.
>   https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian
>   https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=26368